# Is it possible to declare a variable inside an "if" statement?

Tags: c++, variable-declaration

I want to declare a variable inside an "if" statement and do something about the variable after the "if" statement. Here is my simplified code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a;
    cin >> a;

    if (a==1)
        string b;
    else
        int b;

    cin >> b;
    //and some long codes using variable b
}
```

Is it possible to do this? What should I do to declare a variable with different data types(under different conditions) by using the same variable name?

Comment: Yes, but it will be only valid in the scope of the if statement.

Comment: You can't do this. C++ does not work this way. An object, any object, in C++, always has one type, and one type only. This is fundamental to C++. You will need to think of a different way to accomplish whatever goal you need to accomplish.

Comment: No it is not possible.   You will need to design your project so it doesn't rely on such a feature.    Templates allow writing functions that can work on various types, and it is possible to call a different instantiation of a templated function based on user input.     But templates do not provide a means to have one variable name with selectable different types, all in the same scope - they provide a means of having variables of distinct types, each in a different scope, with the same set of operations performed on all types.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for the impossible in C++.   Answers appear to be attracting downvotes if they provide alternatives that may suit the OP's actual need, but don't actually provide the impossible solution sought.

Answer (score 2):

No.
You cannot  have a global scope for the variable you declare inside any local code block. The variables are local to the block it is declared in.

But you can think of using functions for "long_code_block_using_b" that you call inside the same block as the variable being declared
 again if you do the same thing for all data types you can use function templates as below.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
T long_code_using_variable_b()
{
    T b;
    cin >> b;
    //and some long codes using variable b
    return b;
}
int main() {
    int a;
    cin >> a;

    if (a==1)
        cout << long_code_using_variable_b<string>();
    else
        cout << long_code_using_variable_b<int>();

 }
```

Comment: Even I am starting to learn templates. Wouldn't be causing error if you move the declarations inside the function?(Or is there some way we can do it?) And about passing by value I agree that an 'indeterminate value' would be passed to the function but won't that be overwritten when you do a cin inside the function?

Comment: You seem to be familiar with C. I am not sure whether the rules are different in C, but using an indeterminate value (uninitialized `int b;`) to initialize another variable (the function parameter of `long_code_using_variable_b`) causes undefined behavior in C++ (except for some specific types, `int` not included). (I am pretty sure, haven't checked the standard right now)

Comment: You can declare `b` as `T b;` inside `long_code_using_variable_b` instead of having it be passed as argument. That is what I mean. Because it isn't used outside `long_code_using_variable_b` anyway. You will of course need to specify the template arguments explicitly then at the callsite: `long_code_using_variable_b<int>()` and `long_code_using_variable_b<string>()`

Comment: Btw. you can pass by reference instead of value by using `T long_code_using_variable_b(T& b)`. Then my point about undefined behavior wouldn't apply. (But I think the other solution is the cleaner one.)

Comment: Would cause an error "candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'T'" if I remove the declarations outside the function and add a declaration statement like this inside the function.

Comment: Agreed. Updated. Thanks